# How to (elegantly) persist Swift enum with associated values - or should I avoid them?

Tags: swift, core-data, enums, realm

I am caught up in the wonderful expressivity of Swift, and was going to use an enum with associated values for each case, such as this:

```
enum PlayerStatus {
    case Playing (league: Int, position: Int)
    case NotPlaying (ReasonNotPlaying, LastPlayed)
}

enum ReasonNotPlaying {
    case Injured
    case Away
    case DidntPlay
    case Left
}

struct LastPlayed {
    let year: Int
    let position: Int
}

class Player {

    var firstName: String = ""
    var surname: String = ""
    //  etc

    var status: PlayerStatus? = nil
}
```

However, I need to PERSIST the Player class that contains the enum, and neither Realm nor CoreData have any simple mechanism to do this - possibly because enums with associated values are not available in Objective-C (or, in the case of Realm, in Android?)

Have I misunderstood enums? Is my example perhaps NOT clear? Or how can I persist the enum concisely?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Currently, Realm does not support storing Enum. So there is no easy way to store Enum with associated value straightforward.

The workaround that I suggested is like the following:

Extract the enum value to properties. Then override the enum's setter/getter to convert the enum values to the properties every set/get. It seems too complex, but usage is very simple, just set/get `status` property as normal.

```
enum PlayerStatus {
    case Playing (league: Int, position: Int)
    case NotPlaying (ReasonNotPlaying, LastPlayed)
}

enum ReasonNotPlaying: String {
    case Injured
    case Away
    case DidntPlay
    case Left
}

struct LastPlayed {
    let year: Int
    let position: Int
}

class Player: Object {
    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var surname: String = ""
    //  etc

    private let playingLeague = RealmOptional<Int>()
    private let playingPosition = RealmOptional<Int>()

    private dynamic var reasonNotPlaying: String? = nil

    private let lastPlayedYear = RealmOptional<Int>()
    private let lastPlayedPosition = RealmOptional<Int>()

    var status: PlayerStatus? {
        get {
            if let league = playingLeague.value,
                let position = playingPosition.value {
                return PlayerStatus.Playing(league: league, position: position)
            } else if let year = lastPlayedYear.value,
                let position = lastPlayedPosition.value,
                let reason = reasonNotPlaying {
                return PlayerStatus.NotPlaying(ReasonNotPlaying(rawValue: reason)!,
                                               LastPlayed(year: year, position: position))
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                switch newValue {
                case let .Playing(league, position):
                    playingLeague.value = league
                    playingPosition.value = position

                    reasonNotPlaying = nil
                    lastPlayedYear.value = nil
                    lastPlayedPosition.value = nil
                case let .NotPlaying(reason, lastPlayed):
                    playingLeague.value = nil
                    playingPosition.value = nil

                    reasonNotPlaying = reason.rawValue
                    lastPlayedYear.value = lastPlayed.year
                    lastPlayedPosition.value = lastPlayed.position
                }
            } else {
                playingLeague.value = nil
                playingPosition.value = nil

                reasonNotPlaying = nil
                lastPlayedYear.value = nil
                lastPlayedPosition.value = nil
            }
        }
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["status"]
    }
}
```